# How to extract exponent and Modulus in .pem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, rsa, pem

I have a Private.pem file i need to extract the private exponent and Private modulus .Is their any method to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project we did write a objective-c wrapper around openSSL to achieve this.

Comment: No i can't sorry, but it is not that hard to do. have a look at this project http://septicus.com/products/opensource/